# Woocommerce REST API subscriptions filter by parent_id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using Woocommerce REST API to retrieve some data, code provided by Woocommerce team to use as [client](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php)

My client options:

```
'wp_api' => true,
'version' => 'wc/v1',
'ssl_verify'      => false,
'wp_api_prefix' => '/wp-json/',
'query_string_auth' => true,
```

Have a function to retrieve subscriptions:

```
function get_wc_subscriptions($sid=0, $parent=null, $page=1, $offset=0)
{
    $params['page'] = $page;
    $params['offset'] = $offset;
    $params['role'] = 'all';

    if($sid > 0) {
        $endpoint = 'subscriptions/'.$sid;
    } else {
        $endpoint = 'subscriptions';
    }

    if(isset($parent) && ($parent != null)) {
        $params['filter[parent_id]'] = $parent;
    }

    return $this->wooClient->get($endpoint, $params);

}
```

Parent parameter is not working, when calling function without any params, I get a result of all subscriptions on first page, if parent is set, get same result with all subscriptions (not being filtered).

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**
How can I use get_wc_subscriptions?

```
require_once('woosync.php');

$sid = $_GET['sid'];
$parent = $_GET['parent'];
$woosync = new woosync();
$subscriptions = $woosync->get_wc_subscriptions($sid, $parent);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($subscriptions);
```

Comment: Please post your code that calls the API

Comment: Or rather, I should ask you what is calling `get_wc_subscriptions()`? Your code example seems to be missing a piece.

Comment: `$this->wooClient` is an instance of Client class in `Automattic\WooCommerce\` created with `$this->wooClient = new Client( ...`